# Laravel 5 : Couldn't instancing a model using tinker

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm very new to laravel and PHP MVC frameworks, it's my first use of Eloquent. I'm trying to following a [video tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/8).

So after creating a table by making new migration and migrate with artisan.
I created a model.Then I tried to instance it using tinker tool like so :

```
>>> $task = new App\Task;
```

I got this error :

```
=> App\Task {#672}
```

this my model class :

```
class Task extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tasks';
}
```

I did many research before asking this question, some people recommends using homestead, but I want to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The output you got is not an error.

Comment: @peaceman The model was instanced then?

Comment: Yup, the model is instantiated but not saved to the database.

Comment: Peaceman Is model need to be saved to the database? I do not now how to do that? I thought is just created to do operations on the database.

Comment: Yeah, usually you want to save your model to the database. For further base knowledge about Eloquent you should read the official documentation. http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent

Comment: @peaceman aah sorry, you mean the model object http://laravel.io/forum/06-11-2014-how-to-save-eloquent-model-with-relations-in-one-go?page=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an error. It shows that an Object of `App\Task` Class has been created.
Now you can assign values to this `$task` Object. Like we have a field 'name' in tasks table then the following part of code can save the `$task` in database with value of 'name' field.

```
$task = new App\Task;
$task->name = 'My first task';
$task->save();
```